# Flutter FCM IOS no valid aps-environment String found

Tags: flutter, firebase-notifications

I have created identifier and have added certificate to that.When i run my app on IOS device i am getting below in logs.

```
    8.3.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM012002] Error in application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:
 no valid “aps-environment” entitlement string found for application
    8.3.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM002022] APNS device token not set before retrieving FCM Token for Sender ID '137210307895'. Notifications to this FCM Token will not be delivered over APNS.Be sure to re-retrieve the FCM token once the APNS device token is set.
```

I have followed all the steps of connecting firebase and flutter IOS but still see this error. Any one know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I created new csr on mac. Used that certificate on identifier and then created new provision profile and used that profile for the app. The issue was resolved.